# Magento 2 Admin has no style

Tags: magento2

I'm setting up a copy of a client's M2 site to use as a dev environment on a different server.  I've copied all the files, set up the DB blah blah.
The frontend works as intended but the admin area has no style.  Looking at the source it looks like it's trying to load its style from a folder that doesn't exist.

```
/static/version1522232216/_cache/merged/503fa0dfba01298acb5220a0df5638de.min.css
```

The `version1522232216` doesn't exist.

I've run static-content deploy, reindexed, cleared cache etc.  All permissions on the server have been double checked.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be versioning is enabled on server, so disable it by running below query into your database and then check.

**Below is the query :**

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

After that run below command in sequence :

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: Perfect.  That path already existed so I just ran update to change it to 0...

    update core_config_data set value='0' where path='dev/static/sign';

Comment: Yes , Update it and changed it it will works !! let me know if still its not