# Magento 2.4 Backend Admin is showing text only? Why large magento logo on login and no admin?

Tags: admin, error, text

I have a new install of magento 2.4 and i set it up for a custom domain and HTTPS and now when I go to the / admin panel I get a large Magento logo with no formatting and when I login the backend shows text only and no formatting for any of the panels.  I was researching it a little and saw it might be an issue with the document root.  I ran the cache clean and reindex commands and it looks the same and think something isn't configured correctly.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Saw this thread but not sure if it speaks to my problem says "versioning" in enabled: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220213/magento-2-admin-has-no-styleMight be versioning is enabled on server, so disable it by running below query into your database and then check.

Below is the query :

insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null

Comment: Nothing below has worked for me.  Was able to login to the backend using only the IP but then when I configured the domain, I get a login loop on the backend and then get the admin page with out any styling after I accept the HTTPs exception.  I don't have HTTPs set up yet but it should be working fine.  What's the deal?

Comment: Have you try https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/353420/82670 ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user under which php is running (**ussualy www-data:www-data**)  has read and write permissions in the ***./pub/static*** folder. You can view it with the command **ls -l**
[image].

If your user and group under which php runs are different from those that you observe, then you need to change the owner, as well as read and write permissions.

*enter from folder root*

```
 - sudo chmod -R 775 ./pub/static 
 - sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ./pub/static
```

> the same rights are necessary
> distribute to folders ./generated/, ./var/

again, I repeat, it may not necessarily be www-data for you, to find out you can try to enter in the console ***ps aux | grep php***  [image]

After that, you need to rebuild the project, for this in the console:

```
php bin/magento set:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:f
```

P.S. In any case, you can safely try deleting the **./pub/static** folder (**rm -rf ./pub/static**) and then running the command above again, it won't hurt anything, because the folder is generated by magenta. It will simply create a new version of the static files.

If suddenly this did not help you in any way, then you need to look at the log files in the ***./var/log/*** folder and further understand what the problem might be.

Comment: /bitnami/magento/pub/ ls -l

-rwxrwxrwx  1 bitnami daemon 1038 Mar  1 20:09 cron.php

drwxrwxrwx  3 bitnami daemon 4096 Mar  1 20:09 errors

-rwxrwxrwx  1 bitnami daemon 2892 Mar  1 20:09 get.php

-rwxrwxrwx  1 bitnami daemon 3481 Mar  1 20:09 health_check.php

-rwxrwxrwx  1 bitnami daemon  821 Mar  1 20:09 index.php

drwxrwxrwx 15 bitnami daemon 4096 Mar  8 15:25 media

drwxrwxrwx  3 bitnami daemon 4096 Mar  1 20:09 opt

drwxrwxrwx  4 bitnami daemon 4096 Mar  9 13:25 static

-rwxrwxrwx  1 bitnami daemon  445 Mar  1 20:09 static.php

Answer (score 0):

> *Try to run below command:*

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area adminhtml -f
```